# Замена Id на Name по связи с другой таблицей

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

[image: Таблица]

Как сделать чтобы и в дата гриде и в текстбоксах были не АЙДИШКИ а НАЗВАНИЕ, но при этом чтобы при новом добавлении через инсерт база данных получала бы как параметр не НАЗВАНИЕ а АЙДИ.

[image: Cdzpb]

Comment: А не легче ввести ещё один столбец?

Comment: Какой и зачем? Эта таблица - это через binding source подтянутая таблица из базы, там у меня айдишки

Comment: Так может вы покажете, какая у вас структура и что конкретно вам в ней надо?

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev добавил структуру. Мне нужно так чтобы в программе пользователь работал исключительно с названиями, а база работала с айдишками. То есть пользователь добавляет товар указывая его GoogLineName, а база по этому названию вписывает в таблицу Goods соответсвующее айди

Comment: Ещё раз. Давайте на примере. А то, к сожалению, не потянто. Что есть `goodID`, и что есть 'соответствующий айди'. Или вообще работать надо с `GoodLineID`. Как-то вы равно даёте задачу. Сформулируйте более развернуто, тогда получится вам помочь

Comment: Есть 3 таблицы в базе данных, их структура выше на рисунке. Я с помощью bindingsource вывожу таблицу Goods на форму в datagridview. Рядом текстбоксы для того чтобы пользователь мог редактировать эту таблицу. Но проблема в том что мне нужно чтобы по связям, в таблице Goods поля GoodLineID и TypeID заменялись на GoodLineName и TypeName соответственно. Я знаю что у комбобокса есть свойства Value Member и как-то можно отображать GoodLineName в комбобоксе, но при этом когда пользователь допустим сменит тот же GoodLineName то будет меняться соответствующая айдишка в Goods.

Comment: Я могу вывести все  нужные мне данные из базы с помощью запроса SELECT .. FROM GoodsINNER JOIN Types ON Types.TypeID = Goods.TypeID, но тогда проблема в том, что возникают ошибке при их редактировании пользователем ( запросе update )

Comment: Или при запросе Insert... Запрос ждет @TypeID а получает Typename